# Is all user input in a website app considered a form?

Tags: forms, input-fields

We have a complex web app with graphs and panes. Some of the information is entered in popups, while other information is in fields that can appear in cards, tables, and separate fields. Some of the information appears in a Properties pane when you display a graph. (Master/Details view).

When we discuss user input - are all types of input considered a "form"?

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you consider an input. Yes, most things requiring a user to enter information into an interface do so through forms.

However, you could argue something like rotating an object or dragging it to change position (think Illustrator) is an input that does not require a form. Your input is changing the object's positioning and rotation, and those are translated into degrees and coordinates that are fed into the system. But your input was never through a form (typing the rotation or coordinates) but through your action with the mouse.

Comment: What about "excel-like" sheets. are they forms?

Comment: It can be considered a form. You can say forms are limited to: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp, and tables (aka excel sheets) vs forms can be quite blurry: http://jkorpela.fi/forms/tables.html